# Modify anchor link depending on select box value

Tags: jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I want to use a `<select>` drop-down to set the `href` of a link to different anchor values.
Thanks in advance

I currently have this JS:

```
var destinationchange = $("#destination").val();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#destination").change () {
    $("#engage").attr("href" , destinationchange);
  });
});
```

And this HTML:

```
<select id="destination">
  <option value="#1">1</option>
  <option value="#2">2</option>
</select>

<a title="engage" id="engage">Engage</a>
```

Comment: You should always explain the problem that you're coming across and what you've tried. It helps other figure out what's going on quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$("#destination").change (function() {
    $("#engage").attr("href", $(this).val());
});
```

**DEMO:**  http://jsfiddle.net/aVqh9/

Answer (score 0):

You get the value on pageload, and never change it. You need to get the value in the event handler

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#destination").on('change', function() {
        $("#engage").prop("href" , this.value);
    });
});
```